# How to save the contents (Not Texts Nor Images) of a form with a custom extension and open the saved custom file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I need some help for the project I am working on for my internship.

In the VB project, I have a windows form (Form1.vb) with a custom user control called WaveForm1 (which acts like the graph of an oscilloscope).  I can run the VB program and assign values to the channels to get the wave forms in the WaveForm1 user control when the project is running.

Then, I need to save the WaveForm1 together with the Channels plotted in the graph under a custom file extension (.gph, .wfm ,..) using a SaveFileDialog.

The saved file should be able to open in the vb project when it is opened with a button (btnOpen) by using a OpenFileDialog.

How the file is opened in the project doesn't matter as long as the saved graph can be viewed. ( Example, the saved file can be viewed in another WaveForm2 control in Form1.vb or it can be viewed in a separate window form.) It would also be fine if the whole formed can be saved and opened again from the project with the btnOpen button control.

I have searched about custom file creations & saving files and all I could find were how to save text files, excel files or images using a StreamWriter/Reader, binaryReader/Writer, and so on.

I would really appreciate any help regarding saving anything other than text files or drawings.

Please feel free to confirm with me if you are not clear about my questions.

Comment: in what form does the graph data exist (not windows form, but data types, structures)?

Comment: Well the option you have left is using your own extention and associate that with your application. Then you would have to handle the file when you get it, parsing the data and such to where it needs to go...

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean but the user control is created in C# using graphics & drawings to get the grids and the coordinates used for the channel locations are saved as floats. It functions just like an oscilloscope screen when it is used in window form application. I need to save the plotted waveform as a custom file so that it can be retrieved from the VB application when necessary.  @Plutonix

Comment: ok, well if a "plotted waveform" is a series of `Points`, you could write a class to save a Collection or `List(of Point)`, and serialize it and maybe some overall scale info.  You'll have to write a TypeConverter for it and then serialize it.  If you are looking to save it to a specific, defined format, you'll have to do some homework.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR hi, I am having a problem to save the properties of the custom user control that is used in the project. May I know how associating the extension would help in saving the custom properties of the user control? ( Example : GraphArea[System.Drawing.Rectangle], GraphAreaColor[System.Drawing.Color], GraphState[Graphics],..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to create a class with some properties then you can save that class using `BinarryFormatter`. You can give your custom extension to that class and save it through `SaveFileDialog` and open it by `OpenFileDialog`.

**Class**

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class myGraph
    Private _value1 As String
    Public Property Value1 As String
        Get
            Return _value1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _value1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _value2 As String
    Public Property Value2 As String
        Get
            Return _value2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _value2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _value3 As String
    Public Property Value3 As String
        Get
            Return _value3
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _value3 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Method to to Save and Load File**

```
''To Save file
Public Sub SaveFile(GRAPH_1 As myGraph)
    ''To Save File
    Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    dlgSave.Filter = "My File|*.grp"
    dlgSave.DefaultExt = ".gpr"
    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
        Using stream As New MemoryStream
            formatter.Serialize(stream, GRAPH_1)
            Using sw As New FileStream(dlgSave.FileName, FileMode.Create)
                Dim data() As Byte = stream.ToArray()
                sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

''To Load fie
Public Function LoadFile() As myGraph
    Dim GRAPH_2 As myGraph = Nothing
    Dim dlgOpen As New OpenFileDialog
    dlgOpen.Filter = "My File|*.grp"
    If dlgOpen.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
        Using stream As New FileStream(dlgOpen.FileName, FileMode.Open)
            GRAPH_2 = TryCast(formatter.Deserialize(stream), myGraph)
        End Using
    End If
    Return GRAPH_2
End Function
```

**How to Use File**

```
''To Save File
Dim GRAPH_1 As New myGraph
With GRAPH_1
    .Value1 = "ABC"
    .Value2 = "XYZ"
    .Value3 = "PQR"
End With

SaveFile(GRAPH_1)


''ToLoad File
Dim GRAPH_2 As myGraph = LoadFile()
If GRAPH_2 IsNot Nothing Then
    ''Place your code here
    ''And assign values to your graph from that (myGraph)class.
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I am trying it out but I still don't know  whether it will work or not yet since the WaveForm user control have several public properties. 
( Example : GraphArea[System.Drawing.Rectangle], GraphAreaColor[System.Drawing.Color], GraphState[Graphics],..) They are all created in the project for user control. Do I need to add them in the class in my project as well? And how do I relate the above program with the WaveForm1 user control so that its conditions can be saved? @Wulworine

Comment: You should not add controls in that class. just store their values only. because if any control does not marked as serializable then it could not be serialized. You should create some properties to store that control's value and when u load that file you need to assign values back to that control from loaded class object.

Comment: `<Serializable()>
Public Class myGraph
  Private _value1 As Color
  Public Property Value1 As Color
    Get
      Return _value1
    End Get
      Set(value As Color)
      _value1 = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class`
that is the sample code i used in the Class
Then I used the same SaveFile() sub and add the following codes under a button click
`Dim _waveform1 As New myGraph
With _waveform1 
 .Value1 = WaveForm1.GraphAreaColor
End With
SaveFile(_waveform1)
End Sub`
It doesn't save anything.(the size of the created file is 0 bytes) Do you have any suggestions? Thank you. @Wulworine

Comment: I have modified my code for `SaveFile` and `LoadFile`. Now, It is tested and in working condition. :)