# How to save a list of buttons properties as an xml file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 100 buttons in a panel. These buttons change backcolor when clicked. I have made a list of these buttons.

```
    public void buttonList()
    {

        List<Button> panelButtonList = this.panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();

    }
```

I want to write the current backcolor of each of these 100 buttons to a file when I press a save button. I am learning is xml best for this? where can I go for information I cant seem to find much. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What will you do with the file once you have created it? A simple CSV file might serve your purpose too.

Comment: I agree with @shree.pat18 if you are going to process the file in the same order as what you wrote it, I would just save it to a normal comma seperated text file, and then when you want to reset the color from the file just process it in order again

Comment: Basically once the file is written. I want to represent it as a treeview node. Then when i click the treeview node the file will load and change the backcolor of the buttons in the panel. CSV will work for that?

Comment: Serialize the button. That is a very good way of converting an object to xml.

Comment: Serialize the button `object`? ... Please don't (you cannot really) ... you need a list of colors .... just serialize this - ANY file format will do, start with the simplest you can understand and implement right now (if it's a text-file with one color or color-component per line it's *fine*, cause you only toying around right .... **right**!?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your class object in xml or binary file format. To store the object in xml format you need to use `XML Serialization` and `Binary Serialization` for binary formatter.

but, storing a whole button object in a file is not a good idea, You should store only some properties which is required instead of whole class object. BTW, some controls and classes are not supported to serialize in XML and Binary format.

**@Nimesh** has already given suggestion to store your object properties in a binary file format. Look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028026/3761928).** The code is written in VB language. you can convert it into C# using some online code converter [tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Although, Binary serialization is much faster than xml serialization.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a xml defined like following

```
<ControlItemConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
<Instance name="buttonName1">
<_bColor>16777215</_bColor>
<_fColor>-16761747</_fColor>    
<Text>Text1</Text>
</Instance>
<Instance name="buttonName2">
 <_bColor>16777215</_bColor>
<_fColor>-16761747</_fColor>
<Text>Text2</Text>
</Instance></ControlItemConfig>
```

Your buttons will be identified by following class ControlItemConfig Instance.

Create a serializable class like following

```
  [Serializable]
public class ControlItemConfig
{
    public List<Instance> InstanceCollection { get; set; }
    class Instance
    {
        public Instance()
        {
            _bColor = string.Empty;
            _fColor = string.Empty;
            Text = string.Empty;
            Name =string.Empty;
        }
        public string _bColor { get; set; }
        public string _fColor { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Export your buttons data to XML using ControlItemConfig class and read via it.